# Compiling my Kotlin tests inside of git bash

Tags: kotlin, gradle, compilation, git-bash, intellij-14

I am trying to run my code in git bash so that I don't have to run it in Intellij. It runs smoothly inside of Intellij but is giving me issues when I try and compile it inside of gitbash.

Here is the body of code that I am able to run inside of Intellij. The code runs and the test passes when I run it in Intellij.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*
import testCases.TestCases
import testCases.BaseUser


@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation::class)
class AllTests : BaseUser() {

    @BeforeAll
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun initAll() {
        this.initialize()
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    fun runAllTests(){

        try{
            TestCases()

        }catch(ex: Exception){
            Assertions.fail<Any>()
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to run and compile it by doing this inside of git bash:

```
kotlinc AllTests.kt -include-runtime -d tests.jar
```

I keep seeing multiple errors and am unsure how to resolve them:

```
AllTests.kt:1:12: error: unresolved reference: junit
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*
           ^
AllTests.kt:2:8: error: unresolved reference: testCases
import testCases.*
       ^
AllTests.kt:5:2: error: unresolved reference: TestInstance
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
 ^
AllTests.kt:5:15: error: unresolved reference: TestInstance
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
              ^
AllTests.kt:6:2: error: unresolved reference: TestMethodOrder
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation::class)
 ^
AllTests.kt:6:18: error: unresolved reference: MethodOrderer
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation::class)
                 ^
AllTests.kt:7:18: error: unresolved reference: BaseUser
class AllTests : BaseUser() {
                 ^
AllTests.kt:9:6: error: unresolved reference: BeforeAll
    @BeforeAll
     ^
AllTests.kt:12:14: error: unresolved reference: initialize
        this.initialize()
             ^
AllTests.kt:15:6: error: unresolved reference: Test
    @Test
     ^
AllTests.kt:16:6: error: unresolved reference: Order
    @Order(1)
     ^
AllTests.kt:20:13: error: unresolved reference: TestCases()
            TestCases()
            ^
AllTests.kt:33:13: error: unresolved reference: Assertions
            Assertions.fail<Any>()
            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

It runs in IntelliJ because IntelliJ knows where the jar file for junit is located, so it includes that on the path for running the test. You need to do the same.

You can do it with the `-classpath` option

```
kotlinc AllTests.kt -include-runtime -classpath /path/to/junit.jar:/path/to/other.jar -d tests.jar
```

If you are on windows, separate your jars with `;` instead of `:`.